# Model validation before store sync

Tags: extjs, extjs4, ext.net

Listening on `beforeSync` event of store. Options parameter has hash of all records to be synchronized, broken down into create, update and destroy.

I need to validate them against their model validation rules.

Is it possible?

I tried this but it always returns true:

```
Ext.Array.forEach(options.create, function (item) {
    console.log(item.isValid());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have validators in your models?

Comment: Yes. Presence and length validators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that invalid records are not being inserted in hash of records to be synchronized (options parameter).

Instead I can iterate through store's items:

```
Ext.Array.forEach(st.data.items, function (item) {
    console.log(item.isValid())
} );
```